# How do I get similar domains from database using tags?

Tags: mysql

I do have 100k domain names with tags... table has got only two column called `domain` and `tags`.

Tags are stored with coma after each tags. I want fine how many domains with similar tags say `search,google,searchengine,engine,web,reference` with all of them or any of them in it. How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing exactly how you want to implement this, here's some SQL to get you started:

```
SELECT *
FROM domains
WHERE 
  tag LIKE '*search*' OR
  tag LIKE '*google*' OR
  tag LIKE '*searchengine*' OR
  tag LIKE '*engine*' OR
  tag LIKE '*web*' OR
  tag LIKE '*reference*'
```

Comment: I think you mean % where you have *s.  Far as I know, MySQL doesn't use the * to indicate a wildcard in string matching.